# What are the most important questions to discuss today? / What questions are the most important to discuss today?

Tags: questions

> **What are the most important questions** to discuss today?
>
> **What questions are** the most important to discuss today?

Is there a difference in their meaning? Maybe, some emphasis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further context the two sentences are pretty much equivalent in meaning. The one way they could be different is if there was some particular set of options referred to previously - in that case I'd expect the second question to refer to that set, while the first one would be more general. For example:

> "We have those shirts in sizes XS, S, and M"
>
> "What size is the largest?"
>
> "M is the largest"
>
> "What is the largest size?"
>
> "That would be XXL, but we do not have those currently"

Comment: So, it means the second question is more appropriate. I can't imagine the situation when the first question is appropriate if I correctly understand your example.